# How delete invoice_line_ids and not delete customer_id field?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-16

Actually I want to delete only invoice_lines when change the journal_id, I tryed with this code

```
@api.onchange('journal_id')
def _onchange_journal_izi(self):
    for record in self:
        if record.partner_id:
            for lines in self.invoice_line_ids:
                if record.state != 'posted':
                    lines.unlink()
```

It works well but when change the journal_id field the customer field is deleted too, how avoid that the customer field not delete?[image]

After change the joornal field, the customer field is deleted too
[image]